# developing windows device driver for windows 10 on windows 11

Tags: visual-studio, windbg, visual-studio-2022, wdk

I need to develop a device driver that works with windows 10 (and possibly Windows 11, but mainly it is required for windows 10).

My system is windows 11. One way to develop a driver for windows 10 is to downgrade my windows to windows 10 and then start developing.

so here are my questions:

1. If I develop my driver in windows 11, does it works on Windows
   10?
2. In any case, should I use visual studio 2019 or visual studio 2022? the reason is this message that I found (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk)
3. As I am new in driver development, where is the best place to start? Any tutorial on how to set up the development environment?

Comment: https://codemachine.com/articles/system_setup_for_kernel_development.html There are tons of guides you can find on search engines about how to properly set up driver development environment using a virtual machine. Don't use your host machine for driver testing, as that's too risky.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can go to the property page of your driver project in Visual Studio, and inside the Driver Setting -> General, you can select the target OS to Windows 7, and thus making the driver load/install fine on Windows 7+ machines. (Unless you are using a very new API/feature that only exists on 10+, such as the newest NDIS versions, and in that case you'll need to select it to Windows 10 to support 10+ machines)
2. I suggest using VS2019 for now, as 2022 is fairly new and you could face issues developing drivers with it, and there is no major benefit of using 2022 for driver development currently.
3. I suggest reading the first edition of "windows kernel programming" book by Pavel Yosifovich.